# How to make certain sections of my word doc stand out and look different such as by adding a different background color to the pages of the section?

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, formatting

I have a document with 5 sections `A, B, C, D, E.`

I want to highlight `C` and `E` to have light grey background color. How can I do this?

Some suggestions I read on superuser for similar but not same questions mentioned separating out the documents, managing page numbers and then aggregating into a single pdf file. However, is there any other method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Access the headers of the section and insert a large shape that covers the entire page.

Inserting a shape:

[image]

Two section, the first has a blue shape in the header. The second one doesn't

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the method. However, the issue is that I already have logos in my headers. So working with shape leads to issues with that. Is there another suggestion?

Comment: @sheth7 - can't you put the shape behind the logos of your header?

Comment: I can and it is definitely a workaround, but it is not a neat solution. It makes the page look shabby with several lines, colors etc. I am looking for a neater solution.  Thanks!

Comment: You can generate an image of the page with the logos n place and use that instead of a shape. If there are other constraints, maybe edit your question to list them?